Linux userland C see how much memory the current process is using
I'm trying to figure out the maximum amount of memory that my current multi-threaded program is using from within itself (so Valgrind or time are a no-go).
I've seen lots of where doing a /proc walk is reccomended; however, procfs isn't mandatory to be mounted and your system will (mostly) work without it.
WARNING there may be risks with blindly doing this
umount -l /proc
Because of that I want to avoid using /proc. I know getrusage(2) is available; however there is no guarantee that these fields will be filled out (and likely won't be):
long   ru_ixrss;         /* integral shared memory size */
long   ru_idrss;         /* integral unshared data size */
long   ru_isrss;         /* integral unshared stack size */

It looks like hiwater_vm in mm_struct in task_struct (task_struct -> mm -> highwater_vm) will get me to the correct number of pages and I can live with that; however, I don't know if it's possible to get a process's own task_struct from the kernel.
I know I could always write a module to expose task_struct, but I'm willing to bet there is a way to do this without going that far.
Related:
Memory usage of current process in C

If e.g. time gives you the right numbers, why not inspect its source code?

Try mm->total_vm. That's what task_mem in fs/proc/task_mmu.c uses. This is what sets the VmSize: field in /proc/<pid>/status. Note that the ps command uses /proc/<pid>/status and grabs that field. AFAICT, getrusage doesn't pull in total_vm. /proc is necessary for a number of things, so I think you can rely on it (and should). There is no syscall that conveniently presents mm->total_vm to userspace. Where other OSes provide special syscalls to get system info, linux uses the [special] proc fs to do this. Don't worry ... Be happy ... (with /proc).

Note that if you can install a device driver [or new syscall] to get at mm->total_vm via ioctl/syscall, you are root, and you can force procfs to be mounted if it's not. So, just use the standard/easy/supported way and use /proc

@UlrichEckhardt time uses wait3 which seems to use getrusage as suggested by The Linux Programming Interface in Chapter 26 The wait3() and wait4() system calls perform a similar task to waitpid(). The principal semantic difference is that wait3() and wait4() return resource usage information about the terminated child in the structure pointed to by the rusage argument. This information includes the amount of CPU time used by the process and memory-management statistics. We defer detailed discussion of the rusage structure until Section 36.1, where we describe the getrusage() system call.

@SailorCire, if you don't assume anything for sure, we cannot assess you in determining the amount of memory used by a process, you can be on a system that lacks anything you say and be unable to determine the amount of memory used by a process.  Think on making a symbol table walk yourself and making wrappers around malloc() and free() but this will not say the amount of memory used by malloc for housekeeping.
